# Making an absolutely positioned element fill the width of it's container

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a sidebar that I have positioned absolutely to the right for several reasons. But the problem is that if I have a shorter main content area, the sidebar extends past the content.

Is there a way with CSS that we can get the container to wrap its height around the sidebar (if the sidebar is longer)?

Please this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52jjp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not easy to 'clear' absolutely positioned elements. One way I found of doing it is to get the height in jquery, then apply that height to the container. For example:

`$('#container').height($('#ab_positioned').height());`

Comment: That's a good idea, if something CSS doesn't come up, I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this in straight CSS, sadly. When you absolutely position something, you remove it from the document flow, so it no longer affects the height of the parent.

You can solve it with javascript, as @scott-brown suggested already.

However, I prefer an all CSS solution. You can get a sidebar layout using floats that clears regardless of which side is longer using this markup:

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="content">
    Primary content here.
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    Sidebar content here.
  </div>
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```
.primary {
  float: left;
  width: 66%;
}
.sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 33%;
}
.page:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  zoom: 1;
}
```

The styles on `.page` are called a clearfix ([more details here](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html/)).

The nice thing about this layout technique is that you can swap the `.primary` and `.sidebar` columns without changing the markup, just by changing `float:left` to `float:right`, and vice versa.

The clearfix also means that the parent element will contain the children, so you can set a background color on `.page` if you want, and it will extend all the way to the bottom of whichever column is longer.

Comment: Thanks Scott, that's a great explanation. Unfortunately in this case I have to sticky with the absolute positioning, but this is otherwise the perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `min-height{...}` to `.main-content` or `.pad`, if the sidebar has a fixed height.